# Javascript: Printing the permutations of a string exceeds stack memory?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an approach similar to the one [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/), however, with my code snippet I seem to run out of memory with strings of 2 or 3 characters.

Is it an implementation issue? Or do I need to optimize my code here?

```
function swap(string, a_id, b_id){
    var swapped = new String();
    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
        if (i == a_id)
            swapped += string[b_id];
        else if (i == b_id)
            swapped += string[a_id]
        else
            swapped += string[i];
    }
    return swapped;
}

function permute(index, string){
    if (index == (string.length -1)){
        console.log(string);
    }
    else{
        for (var i = index; i <= string.length-1; i++){
            string = swap( string, i, index );
            permute( i, string );
            string = swap(string, i, index ); // undo it for the next iteration
        }
    }
}

permute(0, "AB");
```

Comment: Your recursion termination condition is somehow wrong.  Try stepping through your code with a debugger.

Comment: You'll need to start at `i = index + 1`, otherwise you never reach the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed 1 issue in your implementation 
`permute( i, string );` inside permute, is not modifying `i` value, mean it has to decrease, i value somehow, somewhere in the loop to stop recursion.

Find difficult to understand the logic, when I saw the actual implementation you [linked](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/).

```
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
}

//get new string
function swap(string, leftIndex, iIndex) {
    //console.log(string);
    var charAtL = string.charAt(leftIndex);
    var charAtI = string.charAt(iIndex);
    string = string.replaceAt(leftIndex, charAtI);
    string = string.replaceAt(iIndex, charAtL);
    return string;
}

function permute(string, leftIndex, rightIndex) {
    if (leftIndex == rightIndex) {
        console.log(string);
    } else {
        for(var i = leftIndex; i <= rightIndex; i++) {
            string = swap(string, leftIndex, i);
            permute(string, leftIndex + 1, rightIndex);
            string = swap(string, leftIndex, i);
        }
    }
}
permute("ABC", 0, 2);
```

I just re-wrote the whole program, and its working fine. Check the console for all permutation values.

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3p0q78gs/1/).